# TableView - action when cell is selected

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have some cells which perform a seque, but I want one cell to log the current user out. How can I set this action to a single cell?

thx, Tim.

Comment: It depends, you could add a gesture recognizer like long press for this purpose and hook this gesture to the cell you want to log the current user out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // User selected a row, so check if it's the logout row or not
    if (indexPath.row == logoutRowIndex) {
        // Logout
        [self logout];
    } else {
        // Perform segue
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender: and return NO for the indexPath of the cell that you want to log out the user. The sender argument will be the cell, so you can get the indexPath from that. If you wanted the first cell to log out the user, you could do this,

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(UITableViewCell *)sender {

    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    if (path.row == 0) {
        // log out the user here
        return NO;
    }else{
        return  YES;
    }
}
```